# Spring db config with 2 data sources - the second connection throws HibernateException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on a Spring project that requires 2 data sources. One is to save user details and the others are to save product's information and other processes.

I defined the database configuration as follow:

```
@Value("${caffein.datasource.url}")
    private String APP_DB_URL;

    @Value("${caffein.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String APP_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME;

    @Value("${caffein.datasource.package.to.scan}")
    private String PACKAGE_TO_SCAN;

    @Value("${caffein.users.datasource.url}")
    private String USERS_DB_URL;

    @Value("${caffein.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String USERS_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME;

    @Value("${caffein.datasource.username}")
    private String USERNAME;

    @Value("${caffein.datasource.password}")
    private String PASSWORD;

    @Value(value = "caffein.hibernate.dialect")
    private String HIBERNATE_DIALECT;

    @Value("${caffein.hibernate.showSQL}")
    private String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("caffein.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties appDataSourceProperties() {
        System.out.println("db url: " + APP_DB_URL);
        logger.info("========Config App Database========");
        DataSourceProperties properties = new DataSourceProperties();
        properties.setDriverClassName(APP_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        properties.setUrl(APP_DB_URL);
        properties.setUsername(USERNAME);
        properties.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        logger.info("DB url: " + env.getProperty(properties.determineUrl()));
        return properties;
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        return hibernateProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("caffein.datasource.configuration")
    public BasicDataSource appDataSource() {
        return appDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Qualifier("appSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean appSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.appDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_TO_SCAN);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("caffein.users.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties usersDataSourceProperties() {
        logger.info("========Users Database========");
        DataSourceProperties properties = new DataSourceProperties();
        properties.setDriverClassName(USERS_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
        properties.setUrl(USERS_DB_URL);
        properties.setUsername(USERNAME);
        properties.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        logger.info("DB url: " + env.getProperty(properties.determineUrl()));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("caffein.users.datasource.configuration")
    public BasicDataSource usersDataSource() {
        return usersDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("usersSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean usersSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(this.usersDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_TO_SCAN);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(this.hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

After defining configuration for databases, the class AbstractDAO contains 2 sessions which are created in the configuration:

```
public class AbstractDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("appSessionFactory")
    protected SessionFactory appSessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("usersSessionFactory")
    protected SessionFactory usersSessionFactory;

}
```

The first Session factory which are `appSessionFactory` work well, for example adding new product using hibernate:

```
public void saveProduct(Product entity) {
        this.appSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }
```

But I can't save a new user using the same way:

```
public void addNewUser(User entity) {
        this.usersSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }
```

So what are the issue in the code?

This is my class UserDAO:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO extends AbstractDAO {

    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = this.usersSessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = criteria.from(User.class);
        criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("username"), username));
        return this.usersSessionFactory.createEntityManager().createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
    }

    public void addNewUser(User entity) {
        this.usersSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }
}
```

The Exception is:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:497)
    at the.caffein.dao.UserDAO.addNewUser(UserDAO.java:23)
    at the.caffein.dao.UserDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1b2174c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
```

Comment: You can't use the same transaction(manager) for both sources.

Comment: the problem is that if I add 2 different transaction managers, the throw ClassCastException: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionHolder`